# PHP Write to file not writing to file

Tags: php

I want my php file to write some text to a text file that I have created but nothing is being written to it.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    if (isset($_POST['comment']))
    {
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];

        $myFile = "testFile.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        $stringData = $comment;
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fclose($fh);
    }
    else
    {
        $comment = 'no comment';

        $myFile = "testFile.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        $stringData = $comment;
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fclose($fh);
    }
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you try? Is PHP even able to write to the file?

Comment: Well, nothing is being written to the file but it's returning no errors at all :o/

Comment: You should check `fwrite()` to see if it returns `false` or `0`, to see if it's not writing anything or if there's an error writing.

Comment: Are you sure `$_POST['comment']` is not an empty string?

Comment: When you fopen() your file with "w" mode parameter you are telling PHP to cleanup the txt file or attempt to create it. If the data passed to the fwrite() function is empty, your output file will obviously be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the file permissions.

Try changing permission if that was the issue:

```
chmod("testFile.txt", 0644);
```